# Error on adding a storage share to the Azure storage account

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm getting the following error on running `terraform apply` after adding an `azurerm_storage_share`.

```
Error: Error checking for existence of existing Storage Share "fileshare"
(Account "sttestforaddingfileshare" / Resource Group "resources"):
shares.Client#GetProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403
-- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. 
Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailure" 
Message="This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
\nRequestId:188ae38b-e01a-000b-35b3-a32ea2000000
\nTime:2020-10-16T11:55:16.7337008Z"
```

I think the reason is most likely that Terraform tries to list existing file shares in the storage account directly accessing the storage account's REST API instead of Azure Resource Manager's REST API.

It failed because there exist firewall rules in place not containing the IP of the host terraform runs on. When I add my laptop's IP to the firewall rules, it works. But it's not the desired behavior.

Do you know any workaround? Any help is appreciated.

My TF configuration is as follows:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version     = "= 2.32.0"
  features {}
}
 
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "resources"
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "vnet"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet" {
  name                 = "snet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  
  service_endpoints = [ "Microsoft.Storage" ]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage" {
  name                     = "sttestforaddingfileshare"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  location                 = var.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  network_rules {
    default_action             = "Deny"
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [ azurerm_subnet.snet.id ]
    bypass = [ "None" ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share" "file_share" {
    name                 = "fileshare"
    storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.storage.name
    quota                = 100
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [azurerm_storage_account_network_rules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_account_network_rules.html) resource to define the Network Rules and remove the Network Rules block defined directly on the `azurerm_storage_account` resource.

Also, you can create your file share via using az CLI instead of the separate resource `"azurerm_storage_share"`

After my validation, with the

```
PS D:\Terraform> .\terraform.exe -v
Terraform v0.13.4
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.32.0
```

It worked when `terraform apply` and `terraform destroy`.

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage" {
  name                     = "nnnstore1"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  location                 = var.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command =<<EOT
    az storage share create `
    --account-name ${azurerm_storage_account.storage.name} `
    --account-key ${azurerm_storage_account.storage.primary_access_key} `
    --name ${var.myshare} `
    --quota 100   
    EOT

    interpreter = [ "Powershell", "-c"]
  }

}
   


resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "test" {
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.storage.name

  default_action             = "Deny"
  virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.snet.id]
  bypass                     = ["None"]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Nancy, many thanks for your answer. Your solution looks handy with an exception. To re-run the local-exec provisioner (e.g. to increase the quota size), you would need to taint the storage account. This would end up with the re-creation of the storage account.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue when attempting to create a storage share for a container group. It was pretty much identical code to yours but with the additional container group.

I came across the issue when deploying the stack as new and I bypassed the error by deploying everything but the storage share component and all references to it.

Then when that was completed I introduced the storage share and redeployed without issue.

Crappy work around but its deployed again.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED for me! Set public access to false or use private end point!

Terraform creates recourse group first, storage account second and file share third. In storage account you most likely have
variable "public_network_access_enabled" default = false

That means that as soon as storage account is deployed you are cut off from accessing it, because you the one accessing it over public cloud and so error “Error checking existence of existing Storage Share……“.  will occur.
Storage account after deployment denies you of access because you set it to denies public access. So you can not create file share inside storage account.

To Fix this create private end point and mention it inside terraform OR just set public access to true so you can deploy fileshare and then set public access to false afterwards.
I did deploy successfully after that