# Unable to access Azure storage from Azure function when building it out in Terraform. 404s and 403s being raised

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions, azure-storage

I have been asked to upgrade our Azure function from Azure 3.7 to 3.42 and ensure that it is only accessible for a specific set of IPs. During this migration, I encountered many problems with the functional app not reaching its storage. I have tried various approaches, all with access failures (403s or 404s).

My latest idea is to build a virtual network, place a security group on it to control the incoming IPs, and then place the application and its storage in that virtual network's subnet. It still does not work, failing with the error.

```
Error: retrieving Storage Account: (Name "sa_x" / Resource Group "rg_x"): storage.AccountsClient#GetProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="StorageAccountNotFound" Message="The storage account sa_x was not found."
```

while running `terraform apply`

I have looked at [[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64389436/error-on-adding-a-storage-share-to-the-azure-storage-account]], but I am not sure it applies since it is referring to file shares.

My questions:

1. Am I on the right approach? Should I be using specific `azurerm_storage_account_network_rules` to lock down the storage? Am I missing something fundamental about terraform and Azure storage?
2. Am is using `virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.subnet.id]` correctly to make the storage visible to the subnet?

```
# create an resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "rg-${var.azure_pre}-zzz-sox"
  location = var.resource_group_location
}

#
# Pull all the source files into a zip file to be copied to the function app
#
data "archive_file" "az_zzz_zip" {
  source_dir = "./stage"
  output_path = "./az_zzz.zip"
  type = "zip"
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "securitygroup" {
  name                = "nsg-${var.azure_pre}-zzz-sox"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  security_rule {
    name                       = "AllowHttpsInbound"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "443"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }

  security_rule {
    name                       = "AllowHttpsOutbound"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Outbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

# create the network to hold all these objects
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "vnet-${var.azure_pre}-zzz-sox"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = "subnet-${var.azure_pre}-zzz-sox"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]

}

#
# create a simple storage account for the app
#
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "zzzstorage" {
  name                      = "${var.azure_pre}zipstore"
  resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_tier              = "Standard"
  account_replication_type  = "LRS"
  network_rules {
    default_action = "Deny"
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.subnet.id]
  }
}


resource "azurerm_storage_container" "container" {
  name                  = "content"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.zzzstorage.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}


#
# source code blob
#
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "function_blob" {
  name                   = "az_zzz.zip"
  storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.zzzstorage.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.container.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = data.archive_file.az_zzz_zip.output_path
}


#
##### FAILURE HAPPENS HERE #####
#
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "filestorage" {
  name                      = "${var.azure_pre}soxcompwrk"
  resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_tier              = "Standard"
  account_replication_type  = "LRS"
  network_rules {
    default_action = "Deny"
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.subnet.id]
  }
}


#
##### FAILURE HAPPENS HERE #####
#
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "zzz_logging" {
  name                      = "${var.azure_pre}loggingazcomp"
  resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_tier              = "Standard"
  account_replication_type  = "LRS"
  
  network_rules {
    default_action = "Deny"
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.subnet.id]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_table" "tablelog" {
  name                  = "logging"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.zzz_logging.name
}


# define a service plan
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "service-plan" {
  name                = "${var.azure_pre}-sox-zzz-srv-plan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  os_type = "Linux"
  sku_name = "${var.azure_service_level}"
}


# create the function app, using the resource group name, location, service plan, and storage account
# primary_access_key is an output of creating the storage account
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "zzz-bot" {
  name                       = "${var.azure_pre}-sox-zzz-func"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.service-plan.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.filestorage.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.filestorage.primary_access_key
  virtual_network_subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
  site_config {
  }

  app_settings = ...
}
```

Comment: Update, adding `service_endpoints = ["Microsoft.Storage","Microsoft.Sql"]` to the azurerm_subnet resources, changed my 404, cannot find, for 403, cannot access.

Comment: More success, it seems posting to stack overflow helps, even without an answer, yet.
I made the following changes, to get to a deployment.
- on the storage account, network_rules block, I changed them to 'Apply', so filestores and blobs could be created.  They are in a vnet and so they can talk within it.
- Changed the service plan the app runs under to 'EP1' instead of 'Y1', since the swift networking being used is a premium feature.

Answer (score 0):

With the code , giving network rules for storage account:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "filestorage" {
  name                      = "${var.azure_pre}soxcompwrk"
  resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_tier              = "Standard"
  account_replication_type  = "LRS"
  network_rules {
    default_action = "Deny"
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.subnet.id]
  }
}
```

I was getting same error, with simialr code:

[image]

You can  use code, with Ip rules to allow few ips and restrict in the subnet according to requirement:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "zzzstorage" {
  name                      = "myzipstore"
   location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  account_tier              = "Standard"
  account_replication_type  = "LRS"
  network_rules {
    default_action = "Deny"
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.subnet.id]
    
    ip_rules = [
      "192.0.2.1",
    ]
    
  }
  
}
```

And as you said , the storage blobs to be created are to be of type “Apply”

```
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "function_blob" {
  name                   = "az_zzz.zip"
  storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.zzzstorage.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.container.name
  type                   = "Block"
 // source                 = data.archive_file.az_zzz_zip.output_path
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If specifying network_rules, one of either ip_rules or virtual_network_subnet_ids must be specified and default_action must be set to Deny.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account.html#network_rules